# Creating dynamic model class with a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, odata

I'm trying to create a controller that could get Stored Procedure result without column definition like without model.

I'm thinking that if I can get the column names, I can create a model for that and call Stored procedure with a model. But I could not create a model with looping. Is there any way to create a model with that idea.

Or do you have any idea to get result set without model from stored procedure?

I'm using oData library so it would be great if it can do that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.OData;

namespace WebService.Controllers.OData.Common
{
    public class CallSPWithoutColumnDefinitionController : ODataController
    {
        private SitContextTuborg db = new SitContextTuborg();

        [EnableQuery]
        //[SITAuthorize]
        public IQueryable<CallSPWithoutColumnDefinitionModel> GetCallSPWithoutColumnDefinition()
        { 
        Dictionary<string, string> parameterValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            List<CallSPWithoutColumnDefinitionModel> ReturnValues = new List<CallSPWithoutColumnDefinitionModel>();

            parameterValues.Add("STR_CO_NAME", "Pages");

            var Results = db.ExecuteProcedureWithAuth<CallSPWithoutColumnDefinitionModel>("[Load-Co-Confıg.R01]", this.Request.GetClientIp(), parameterValues).ToList();

            foreach (CallSPWithoutColumnDefinitionModel item in Results)
            {
                ReturnValues.Add(new CallSPWithoutColumnDefinitionModel()
                { 
                    LNG_ID = item.LNG_ID,
                    STR_COLL_NAME = item.STR_COLL_NAME,
                    STR_TYPE = item.STR_TYPE
                });
            }

            return ReturnValues.AsQueryable();
        }
        public class tmpCallSPWithoutColumnDefinitionModel
        {
                //we need to create model with a for loop with Returnvalues' coll names above
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Tuple<string, object[]> PrepareArguments(string storedProcedure, object parameters)
    {
        var parameterNames = new List<string>();
        var parameterParameters = new List<object>();

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in parameters.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                string name = string.Format("@{0}", propertyInfo.Name);
                object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(parameters, null);

                parameterNames.Add(name);
                parameterParameters.Add(new SqlParameter(name, value ?? DBNull.Value));
            }
        }

        if (parameterNames.Count > 0)
            storedProcedure = string.Format("{0} {1}", storedProcedure, string.Join(", ", parameterNames));

        return new Tuple<string, object[]>(storedProcedure, parameterParameters.ToArray());
    }
```

From: http://code-clarity.blogspot.in/2012/02/entity-framework-code-first-easy-way-to.html

Comment: actually  I think something is misunderstood. I have ReturnValues as you see in code as return value.. I need to send it to a model class below and I need to CREATE new MODEL structure ;

something like 
 
        [Column("COLUMN1")]
        public int COLUMN1{ get; set; }

        [Column("COLUMN2")]
        public string COLUMN2{ get; set; }

So I could not send it to class and create a model like above...

Comment: You want to create class from resulting data dynamically?

Comment: If you will create a class dynamically, what would be your return type? Though you can create class dynamically using Reflection

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ExpandoObject from System.Dynamic.

Here's a working example:

```
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("hello", typeof(int)));
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("world", typeof(string)));
        DataRow newRow = tbl.NewRow();
        newRow["hello"] = 1;
        newRow["world"] = "boobies";
        tbl.Rows.Add(newRow);

        foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
        {
            var expando = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
            foreach (DataColumn col in tbl.Columns)
            {
                expando.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col.ColumnName]);
            }
        }
```

What's important here is that when we call Add on that ExpandoObject, it's actually going to add those values as PROPERTIES on that object.  Pretty nifty!

Answer (score 0):

actually I think something is misunderstood. I have ReturnValues as you see in code as return value.. I need to send it to a model class below and I need to 
CREATE new MODEL structure ;

something like

```
[Column("COLUMN1")] public string COLUMN1{ get; set; }
[Column("COLUMN2")] public string COLUMN2{ get; set; }
```

So I could not send it to class and create a model like above..